# Is there a web app where you can share music in real time in the context of a chat?

Tags: webapp-rec, chat, music

I'm looking for a web application that allows me to share the music I'm listening to **in real time** with a friend over chat. Note: this isn't about broadcasting my musical tastes or publishing my history.

The use case is: I'm listening to a rockin' track while I'm chatting with my friend. And I want to be able to show him by allowing him to stream my track. The music would be sync'ed so that I could point out the parts that I really like.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Someone finally built it:

http://outloud.fm

Comment: And that site, as it originally existed, is now gone :(

Answer (score 0):

Hangout can post YouTube videos. Most songs are on there.